# Django: Booking() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chek_in'

Tags: django

I'm creating a booking appin django and I'm a bit new on this, when I try to book a room I keep getting the following error:
**Booking( ) got an unexpected keyword argument 'chek_in'**
I'm following the code on the following git address, but I keep making the same mistake no matter how many times I keep writing the code:

*https://github.com/Darshan4114/Django_HMS*

I appreciate any help you can bring. Below my codes:

Availability.py

```
import datetime
from hotel.models import Room, Booking

def check_availability(room, check_in, check_out):
    avail_list = []
    booking_list = Booking.objects.filter(room=room)
    for booking in booking_list:
        if check_in > booking.check_out or booking.check_out < check_in:
            avail_list.append(True)
        else:
            avail_list.append(False)
    return all(avail_list)
```

Views

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import ListView, FormView, View
from .models import Room, Booking
from .forms import AvailabilityForm
from hotel.booking_functions.availability import check_availability

class RoomListView(ListView):
    model=Room

class BookingList(ListView):
    model=Booking   

class RoomDetailView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        category = self.kwargs.get('category', None)
        form = AvailabilityForm()
        room_list = Room.objects.filter(category=category)
        
        if len(room_list)>0:
            room = room_list[0]
            room_category = dict(room.ROOM_CATEGORIES).get(room.category, None)
            context = {
            'room_category': room_category,
            'form': form,
            }
            return render(request, 'room_detail_view.html', context)
        else:
            return HttpResponse ('Category does not exist')

            
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        category = self.kwargs.get('category', None)
        room_list = Room.objects.filter(category=category)
        form = AvailabilityForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
        
        available_rooms=[]
        for room in room_list:
            if check_availability(room, data['check_in'], data['check_out']):
                available_rooms.append(room)

        if len(available_rooms) > 0:
            room = available_rooms[0]
            booking = Booking.objects.create(
                user=self.request.user,
                room=room,
                chek_in=data['check_in'],
                check_out=data['check_out'])
            booking.save()
            return HttpResponse(booking)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('No rooms available on this category. Please try another one')

class BookingView(FormView):
    form_class = AvailabilityForm
    template_name = 'availability_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        data = form.cleaned_data
        room_list = Room.objects.filter(category=data['room_category'])
        available_rooms=[]
        for room in room_list:
            if check_availability(room, data['check_in'], data['check_out']):
                available_rooms.append(room)
                
        if len(available_rooms) > 0:
            room = available_rooms[0]
            booking = Booking.objects.create(
                user=self.request.user,
                room=room,
                chek_in=data['check_in'],
                check_out=data['check_out']
            )
            booking.save()
            return HttpResponse(booking)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('No rooms available on this category. Please try another one')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you misspelled `check_in` in your BookingView  and RoomDetailView 
 `chek_in=data['check_in'],`

Comment: Thank you so much... I knew I was missing something really basic, and I've spent several hours trying to find it, highly appreciate it.